# unable to add notificationconfiguration to s3 bucket

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation, sam

Created cloud formation template to create bucket with notification.

Following is code:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'

Parameters:
  CBRS3ToS3IADelay:
    Description: Number of days before an S3 object is transitioned from S3 to S3-IA
    Type: Number
    Default: 365
  CBRS3ToGlacierDelay:
    Description: Number of days before an S3-IA object is transitioned from S3-IA to Glacier.
    Type: Number
    Default: 1460
  CBRBucketName:
    Description: S3 bucket name
    Type: String
    Default: "my-bucket-test0011"

Resources:
  CBRS3Bucket:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
    Properties:
      BucketName:
        Ref: CBRBucketName
      AccessControl: Private
      LifecycleConfiguration:
        Rules:
          - Id: CbrCertReportGlacierArchiveRule
            Status: Enabled
            Transitions:
              - StorageClass: STANDARD_IA
                TransitionInDays: !Ref CBRS3ToS3IADelay
              - StorageClass: GLACIER
                TransitionInDays: !Ref CBRS3ToGlacierDelay
      NotificationConfiguration:
        LambdaConfigurations:
          -
            Function: "arn:aws:lambda:xxxx:xxxx:function:xxxx"
            Event: "s3:ObjectCreated:Put"
            Filter:
              S3Key:
                Rules:
                  -
                    Name: suffix
                    Value: ".gz"
      Tags:
        - Key: PRODUCT
          Value: CRAWS
      VersioningConfiguration:
        Status: Enabled
```

Code working with notification block.
But above template is not working with notification.

Getting following error:

```
Unable to validate the following destination configurations (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidArgument
```

I able to do from console.

Anyone help me to fix this issue?

Comment: Is this the full CFN template? Have a look at this, it might be related: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/unable-validate-destination-s3/

Answer (score 4):

this is late, so more of answering myself for this question (just managed to fix the same problem): it fails due to a preliminary check on s3 to invoke that lambda function, we will need this:

```
  CBRS3BucketCanInvokeFunctionX:
    Type: 'AWS::Lambda::Permission'
    Properties:
      FunctionName: ARN_OF_FUNCTION_X
      Action: 'lambda:InvokeFunction'
      Principal: s3.amazonaws.com
      SourceAccount: !Ref 'AWS::AccountId'
      SourceArn: !Sub 'arn:aws:s3:::${CBRBucketName}'
```

your CBRS3Bucket will also need to let above resource run first:

```
  CBRS3Bucket:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
    DependsOn: CBRS3BucketCanInvokeFunctionX
```

Answer (score 0):

Try taking the .gz and put in just gz.